# MySQLi должно возвращает одно значение

Tags: php, php7

В классе реализую метод который должен возвращать одно значение.
Меня похоже заклинило нужна подсказка.

```
public function selectAccessLevel($userID) {
    $query = "SELECT value FROM groups WHERE id='" . $userID . "' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    if ($result) {
        return $result->??????????????;
    }
```

Какую функцию использовать для возврата одного значения?

Comment: Ну, судя по вашей функции то возвращаться должна переменная `$result`... У вас запрос этот `$query` возвращает 1 значение... Соответственно, вам его и надо возвращать у `return`, разве нет?

Comment: я вардампом вывел переменную result object(mysqli_result)#7 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: раньше я ретурнил не одно поле и писал так return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);

Answer (score 0):

Результат достигнут!

```
public function selectAccessLevel($userID) {
    $query = "SELECT value FROM groups WHERE id='" . $userID . "' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    if ($result) {            
        return $result->fetch_assoc()['value'];            
    }
}
```

Мне кажется все таки что это не корректно. Было бы неплохо что бы меня поправили.